# Setting Animation behaviour for UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I have an image view which is a circle with the upper half in black and the lower half as white with another black circle at the center.

If I swipe up then the white color should increase from both the ends simultaneously... I have added a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` and gestures are detected

1. How to increase the color from the lower half using animation?
2. Is there a way where I can set alpha value while swiping up, using animation?

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

1. A swipe gesture is a one-shot. It fires once, and doesn't give you a chance to animate as the user drags. You want a pan gesture recognizer for that.
2. There is no off-the-shelf animation that will animate color changes to different parts of the image as you describe. You'll have to create your own. Your description is kind of vague, so it's a bit hard to give you suggestions. Do you want to replace the previous contents of your image view with pure white, coming from the top and bottom, or do you want to brighten your original image view towards white? You need to describe the effect you're after in a lot more detail. You could probably get the effect you are after using Core Animation and either a CAGradientLayer or a CAShapeLayer. A gradient layer could act as either an overlay that would cover the image view underneath, or as a mask that would reveal a new image on top in the final state you're after.

As to your question #2, animating the alpha is trivial. Again, you need to use a pan gesture recognizer, not a swipe gesture recognizer. Then you could adjust the alpha value of the view as the pan position moves up the view. You could also trigger a crossfade style animation with a swipe gesture, and use UIView animation methods like `animateWithDuration:animations:`